# mariadb, PHP7 -- cannot grant all DB privs

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Within my PHP code, I've tried various iterations of this directive:

```
        $dbc->exec("CREATE DATABASE $dbName;
                    CREATE USER '$user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$pass';
                    GRANT ALL ON $dbName.* to '$user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$pass';
                    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;")
```

And, by iterations, I mean tweaking the db privilege values:

- `$dbName`.*
- $dbName.*
- $dbName
- '$dbName'.*
- and so on...

For all attempts, I end-up with a user created with the GRANT USAGE statement and non-bound (associated) with the targeted database ($dbName).

The one and only time I've gotten this to work successfully is by changing the privilege levels to *.* which grants everything for all databases for this user which I am trying to avoid; I'd like to limit the grant to the named database only. Instead, when I exec a GRANT ALL, or GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES, of ending up with this result every time:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for someAdmin@localhost;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for someAdmin@localhost       
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'someAdmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '[snip]' |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've also tried restarting mariadb after issuing the commands just to see if the restart would force the correct privs but nope.

**What's the correct SQL to grant all privileges on the database (with grant option) to the new user s.t. the user is actually granted *all privileges* on the named db?**

*(PHP 7.2, MariaDB 10.1, Ubuntu 18.04)*

> From the MariaDB Doc:
>
> Global privileges are granted using *.* for priv_level. Global
>   privileges include privileges to administer the database and manage
>   user accounts, as well as privileges for all tables, functions, and
>   procedures. Global privileges are stored in the mysql.user table.
>
> Database privileges are granted using db_name.* for priv_level, or
>   using just * to use default database. Database privileges include
>   privileges to create tables and functions, as well as privileges for
>   all tables, functions, and procedures in the database. Database
>   privileges are stored in the mysql.db table.

Comment: I'd suggest separating out each line into their own query, instead of passing it all as one. It may not be running all lines.

Comment: Executing the queries individually produces the same results.

Comment: Mind the SQL injections? Also consider not making a MySQL user from application code as it is not safe..

Comment: Opinion.  Neither relevant or useful.

Comment: SQL injections comment was pretty relevant as your code looks to be prone to that.. Which isn't a Opinion..

Comment: For the rest of the pending a.r. commentary - please note this is just a simple stub and an incomplete one at that.  Forget about all the i-dotting and t-crossing and help with a solution instead of picking lint.  Thank you.

Comment: pretty sure by the way you are looking to the wrong MySQL account.. you run show grants on the  MySQL user that has  `localhost` as domain but you create/grant on the MySQL user which has `%` as domain/IP wildcard (can connect from everywhere assuming the OS firewall is also open on the MySQL port) in the statement..

Comment: Yup - that's my bad...as stated, several iterations.  Doesn't matter if I use '%', 'localhost', '*' or all of the above in multiple statements.  The results are the same.  mariaDB creates a user with GRANT USAGE instead of GRANT ALL to the targeted db.  Again, the challenge is to find the right syntactical combination to achieve the desired results without resorting to a global privilege grant statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query combination worked for me:

```
            $dbc->exec("CREATE DATABASE $dbName;
                        CREATE USER '$user'@'$host' IDENTIFIED BY '$pass';
                        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $dbName.* to '$user'@'$host' IDENTIFIED BY '$pass';
                        FLUSH PRIVILEGES;")
```

The user is bound to the newly-created database with *wildcard:{$dbname}* permissions. Tunneling deeper, I see the user has all abilities, including the one to create indexes and db objects in the new database, except grant, which is what I was really needed.  Globally, the new user still has "usage" level permissions, also desirable.

Thanks for the questions and help - it got my brain kick-started to try different things!

Answer (score 0):

```
'$user'@'%'
'someAdmin'@'localhost'
```

`'%'` does *not* include `'localhost'`, but rather everything else.

The normal pattern is

```
CREATE USER            'user'@'...' IDENTIFIED BY '...';
GRANT ALL ON 'db'.* TO 'user'@'...';
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                       These must match exactly.
```

(In the old days, `GRANT` would `CREATE` the user; in the future (MySQL 8.0) it won't.  MariaDB will probably go that direction eventually.)

As for the `ON 'db'.*`, the dbname is optionally quoted.  (If not quoted, then beware of certain punctuation marks.)  The `*` is a wild card meaning "all of that db".

I think this context allows double quotes, single quotes, or backtics for quoting.

Comment: The user names in the sql directives do match, exactly.  I've tried several variations using single quotes, back-ticks, and no quotes, and it still fails to create db-wide privs instead granting usage privs only.  Initially the code creates two user accounts using localhost and '%' and then exec'd grant statements to both accounts.  This, of course didn't work properly prompting code reduction to a single user in an attempt to get that to work successfully.  Sorry but this is not an solution.  It should be if the code executed in-accordance with the doc.

Comment: @MichealShallop - And the "host" must match exactly.

Comment: @MichealShallop - Start over, list exactly and completely (except for pwd) the commands issued to create the account, plus the failed attempt to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the "%" ?

It's better also to add localhost.
[See this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69525772/485063)