# cannot access mariadb in docker by other user then root

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, synology

I have a docker container with mariadb on a synology nas.
The mariadb version is 10.4.12.
By trying to access the mariadb from a linux client by latest dBeaver I got following behavior.

- Access with root user from client is successfull.
- Access with root user out of inside the docker is successfull.
  so far so fine!
  Then I created following user, by following command:

```
CREATE USER 'myUser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'secretPassword';
GRANT select, update, insert, delete ON mydb.* TO 'myUser'@'%';
```

After this I flushed privileges

With this user I am not able to login from inside the docker container and also not possible from the client.
Dependig from where I tried, I got 'Access denied for user 'myUser'@'172.17.0.1'.

The mariadb charset is UTF8.
The plugin in mysql.user is set to: mysql_native_password
In /etc/mysql/my.cnf the bind is enabled and set to 0.0.0.0

- I tried to create the same user with above listet command with localhost and clientIP also without success.
- I restartet the docker container without success.
- I grant ALL to this user and flushed privileges again, without success.
- I deleted all myUser's and created the myUser@% new with additional usage rights, also without success.

Are there any idea what I can do/ how to fix this behavior?
Any help will be apreciated!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!!
I used for the user an automatic generated password:

```
G(m&amp;&gt;JBR,9ä
```

This did not work. 
After I changed the password to a new one. Everything worked fine!

Are there any restrictions which charactes are possible in a password?

Comment: If you used the password from the command line, it's possible the `&` and `;` characters were interpreted as shell metacharacters. Use single quotes to prevent this e.g. `mysql -u myUser -p'G(m&amp;&gt;JBR,9ä'`

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the "%"

For more convenient, I also add couple of combinations.

```
CREATE USER 'myUser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'secretPassword';
GRANT select, update, insert, delete ON mydb.* TO 'myUser'@'localhost';

CREATE USER 'myUser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'secretPassword';
GRANT select, update, insert, delete ON mydb.* TO 'myUser'@'%';

CREATE USER 'myUser'@'' IDENTIFIED BY 'secretPassword';
GRANT select, update, insert, delete ON mydb.* TO 'myUser'@'';
```